# Update variables in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, state, combine, swiftui-navigationlink

I am not being able to update a variable outside the body of a view.

I have a view that will call the next one when a condition happens in the ViewModel.

Basically I have this variable:

```
@State var shouldGoForSelectAvatarScreen = false
```

That triggers this one:

```
FaceIDView().navigatePush(when: $shouldGoForSelectAvatarScreen, matches: true)
```

Outside the body I have this method:

```
func updateLink() {
    self.shouldGoForSelectAvatarScreen = true
}
```

That is being called, but it doesnt update the value, what should I do to make this work?

The view:

```
public struct ChooseIDView: View {
    var viewModel: ChooseIDViewModel

    @State private var textFieldID = ""
    @Binding var shouldGoForSelectAvatarScreen: Bool
    
    public var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5.0) {
                }
                Spacer()
                ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                    VStack(spacing: 5) {
                        Text("Choose Wzrd ID")
                            .font(.title)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 30)
                            .font(.body)
                            .bold()
                        PrimaryTextField(placeholder: "Enter your name",
                                         secretText: false)
                        PrimaryTextField(placeholder: "Enter your password",
                                         secretText: true)
                        PrimaryButton(action: {
                            self.viewModel.requestAuthorization()
                        }, title: "Next")
                    }.padding()
                }
            }
            FaceIDView()
                .navigatePush(when: $shouldGoForSelectAvatarScreen, matches: true)

            Button("toggle") {
                self.shouldGoForSelectAvatarScreen = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateLink() {
        self.shouldGoForSelectAvatarScreen = true
    }
}
```

And the Coordinator:

```
@MainActor
class ChooseIDViewCoordinator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var parent: LoggedOutCoordinator?
    @State var shouldNavigateToFaceID: Bool = false

    var viewModel = ChooseIDViewModel()
    var mainView: ChooseIDView!

init(parent: LoggedOutCoordinator?) {
    self.parent = parent
}

func view() -> some View {
    mainView = ChooseIDView(viewModel: viewModel, shouldGoForSelectAvatarScreen: $shouldNavigateToFaceID)
    self.viewModel.delegate = self
    return mainView
}
}
```

Comment: Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: `State` is only for a `SwiftUI.View`  change to `Published` inside `ChooseIDViewCoordinator`. Also, every instance of an `ObservableObject` needs an "Object Property wrapper" at every level in a `View`. `StateObject` for initializing, `ObservedObject` for passing around. You should look at the basic Apple SwiftUI tutorials.